# multi-level relationship in laravel mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4

I am working on laravel with mongoDB using [jenssegers](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb). And i am trying to use hasOne relationship on this.

I have MongoDB document which contains following data.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("55558e3d3d1784e01100002a"),
   "title": "Task 3",
   "status": NumberInt(3),
   "type": NumberInt(1),
   "updated_at": ISODate("2015-05-15T11:15:10.0Z"),
   "created_at": ISODate("2015-05-15T06:12:13.0Z"),
   "comments": [
     {
       "id": "QZMV154213",
       "msg": "Testing",
       "date": 1431688333003,
       "user_id": "54b107b9ff39ae580400002a" 
    },
     {
       "id": "QZMV154213",
       "msg": "Testing Of commnets",
       "date": 1431688350531,
       "user_id": "54b107b9ff39ae580400002b" 
    } 
  ],
}
```

I am use following laravel query to get user detail.

```
Task::with('user')->get()->toArray();
```

And Write following in model

```
public function user() {
        return $this->hasMany('User', '_id', 'comments.user_id');
    }
```

It always give me user empty array.How can i do this using laravel MongoDB.

Comment: If I understood your models correctly, the relationship is as follows `Comment belongsTo User` and a `Task embedsMany Comment`?

Comment: Yeah task has many comments and each comment belong to user

Comment: @chridam  Have you any solution for that?